# Count number of occurences based on value from another table

Tags: sql

I have a table called "Reviews" which contains the review ID and the content of the review.

In order to count how many reviews contain a particular keyword, I have used the code.

```
SELECT COUNT(text)
FROM Reviews
WHERE text LIKE '%PC%';
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is instead of "%PC%", I get the keyword from another table which contains a keyword ID and the actual keyword.

With all that I hope the results will be like:

```
COUNT(text) | Keyword
    5       |   PC
    1       |   Computer
```

The count being the number of reviews which contained the particular keyword.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the GROUP BY function:

```
    SELECT COUNT(text), text as Keyword
    FROM Reviews
-- you can use where clause here to filter down your results further
    GROUP BY text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT k.keyword, COUNT(text) cnt
FROM KeywordTable k
LEFT OUTER JOIN Reviews r ON r.text like '%' + k.Keyword + '%'
GROUP BY k.keyword
```

Comment: This is what I'm trying to achieve, but that code only returns 0's.

Comment: can you post data from your tables?